# How to find the activity xml file to which the activity in manifest file corresponds to?

Tags: android, xml

I am an Android newbie, so this question might sound a little silly....

So far, I know that you can know which activity is the Main one (ie which activity is launched when the activity first starts) by finding the intent-filter as such:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

But, my problem is that how does Android know which XML file corresponds to that activity?? I have downloaded some source code for learning, and there are many XML files, each one for a different activity. So, I am kind of lost as to how to find the XML file for one particular activity.....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go in your MainActivity (LAUNCHER Activity) and inside onCreate method look for this :

```
setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
```

the layout under this method argument will solve your issue. Ctrl+click on ".main_activity" will get you to that xml, "main_activity is the name of layout here"

**Note**
procedure will be same for all activities

Answer (score 0):

You just need to find out Activity class for your LAUNCHER intent.

In AndroidManifest.xml, it should be written above LAUNCHER .
After that you can look inside onCreate() method to see which layout this activity uses.